# Structuring an Array of objects

Tags: php, arrays

I have this Open Days array of objects for my project.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Mon] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_NAME] => Mon
        )

    [Tue] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_NAME] => Tue
        )

    [Wed] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_NAME] => Wed
        )

    [Sat] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_NAME] => Sat
        )

    [Sun] => stdClass Object
        (
            [DAY_NAME] => Sun
            [SPECIAL_START_TIME] => 12:00 am
            [SPECIAL_END_TIME] => 08:54 pm
        )

)
```

So, when I need to print the from-open-day, I take the first element of the array, and the to-open-day, I take the end element of the array. 
But in between, Thursday and Friday are closed. 
The resultant view that I need is

```
Mon-Wed, Sat - #some-time-here
Sun - #Some-time-here
```

I am very much confused as to how should I approach this

Comment: Open Days is an object, not an array

Comment: Yes, mu mistake while typing. But, can I get a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So open-to-close times are the unique entities and days are the related entities for each. This indicates a data structure where open-to-close times are keys in a map of related days.
In PHP that would look like this:

```
$out = array(
    '10:00-18:00' => array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Sat'),
    '12:00-17:00' => array('Sun')
);
```

Building this array is done with a single loop through that object:

```
$out = array();
foreach($obj as $day => $data) {
    $time_key = $data->SPECIAL_START_TIME . '-' . $data->SPECIAL_END_TIME;
    if(!array_key_exists($time_key, $out)) { 
        $out[$time_key] = array();
    }
    $out[$time_key][] = $day;
}
```

Now you have to "compact" consecutive days in day ranges (`array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed')` becomes `'Mon-Wed'`):

```
$order = array(
    'Sun' => 0,
    'Mon' => 1,
    'Tue' => 2,
    'Wed' => 3,
    'Thu' => 4,
    'Fri' => 5,
    'Sat' => 6
);

$in = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');

function group_days($in, $order) {
    $out = array();
    $outIndex = -1;

    $prevIndex = -1;
    foreach($in as $day) {
        if($order[$day] - $prevIndex !== 1 || $outIndex === -1) {
            $outIndex += 1;
            $out[$outIndex] = array();
        }
        $prevIndex = $order[$day];
        $out[$outIndex][] = $day;
    }

    return $out;
}

$groups = group_days($in, $order);
foreach($groups as $group) {
    if(count($group) === 1) {
        echo $group[0] . PHP_EOL;
    }
    else {
        echo $group[0] . '-' . $group[count($group) -1] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I compact that? That was my actual question